# Computation of an integral about Fejér kernel

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How can I compute the integral?

$$\lim_ {n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{ \frac { \sin^2(\frac{nx}{2})}{n\,\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})} }\,dx$$

I think it is Fejér kernel application, but I have no idea how to do.

Can someone give me details?

Comment: There is an error in the present expression your integrator is $1/n$, and then the limit is 0...

Comment: I fixed the MathJax, hoping that I did not change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_{-\pi} F_n(x)\ dx = 2\pi
\end{align}
where $F_n(x)$ is the Fejer kernel.

Moreover, we have that
\begin{align}
\int^\pi_{-\pi} F_n(x)\ dx = \int^{\pi/4}_{-\pi/4} F_n(x)\ dx + \int_{\pi>|x|>\pi/4} F_n(x)\ dx
\end{align} 
where
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\pi>|x|>\pi/4} F_n(x)\ dx = 0.
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int^{\pi/4}_{-\pi/4} F_n(x)\ dx = 2\pi.
\end{align}
Since $F_n(x)$ is even, then it follows
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int^{\pi/4}_0 F_n(x)\ dx = \pi.
\end{align}

Comment: Why the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\pi>|x|>\pi/4} F_n(x)\ dx = 0$ ? Could you give me a  hint?

Comment: It's a property of the Fejer kernel. Recall the Fejer "converges" to a delta function.

Comment: @czdh: it is enough to study the stationary points of the function $\frac{\sin(nx/2)}{\sin(x/2)}$ to deduce that $F_n(x)$ is positive but very small on the interval $\left[\frac{2\pi}{n},\pi\right]$.

Comment: This being one of the many areas I totally ignore, do we know how the integral varies with $n$ ? Numerically, it seems to be very slow. Are asymptotics known ? Thanks.

Comment: Interesting, I ran into a similar situation where can one find reading on how the Fejer Kernel's relation to the delta function

Answer (score 1):

Back to the sum definition of the Fejér kernel:
$$ F_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+2\sum_{j=1}^{k}\cos(jx)\right)\tag{1}$$
We may now apply termwise integration: 
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}F_n(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^{k}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi j}{4}}{j}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{n-j}{j}\sin\frac{\pi j}{4}\tag{2}$$
and since $\sum_{j=1}^{m}\sin\frac{\pi j}{4}$ is bounded,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}F_n(x)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4}+2\sum_{j\geq 1}\frac{\sin\frac{\pi j}{4}}{j}=\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{3\pi}{4}=\color{red}{\large \pi}.\tag{3} $$

Comment: This being one of the many areas I totally ignore, do we know how the integral varies with n ? Numerically, it seems to be very slow. Are asymptotics known ? Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: convergence is pretty slow, I agree. We may found more precise asymptotics by dealing with $$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sin(\pi j/4)}{j}$$ through summation by parts.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Without the *Fej$\acute{e}$r Kernel* !!!.

$\bbx{\ds{\mbox{As}\ n \to \infty}}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sin^{2}\pars{nx/2} \over n\sin^2\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x & \sim
{1 \over n}\,n^{2}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}{\sin^{2}\pars{nx/2} \over \pars{nx/2}^{2}}\,\dd x =
n\,{2 \over n}\int_{0}^{n\pi/8}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \sim
2\ \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sin^{2}\pars{x} \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\pi \over 2}} = \bbox[#ffe,10px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\pi}}
\end{align}